# Grouping of data in amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using `maxseries` to disable grouping of data for that I have set its value to `0` so that it will not group data in any groups. But for one month view my axis scale is not consistent see image. Is this is because of grouping of data or there in any other issue.

My main motive to make the gap b/w two lines consistent , if there is no value in db for particular date then scale must shifted to next date so that gap remains same

[image]